# ComboxBox prompting a new form

Tags: c#, combobox

I am making a Window Forms in which I have a combo box where I have inputted all the "search results" I need (attached below) so I was wondering as I have several different inputs(Headache,Weak Immunity and etc.), if it is possible for the picture boxes in my 2nd form to only display pictures relevant to the text in the combo box (Lets say Headache is in the combo box which is in DropDownList style, my 2nd form will show pictures relevant to headaches and not like weak immunity). If I cannot, please let me know what I can do. And I'm using C# in Visual Studio
[The first image is my search items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRyrP.png)

[The second image is my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JFwQ.png)

Comment: _"the following form will only prompt pictures and textbox of that text in the combo box"_ Your question didn't provide any information in regards to this part. What pictures and text box? What exactly do you want to be displayed on the form? Please [edit] the question and try to explain the problem in more detail and include the relevant parts of your code [as formatted text, not as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8967612).

Comment: I have already edited it, hope it makes more sense and I also don't have any code as I am not sure how to start it.